# How to remove identity cookies on sign out or invalid user credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

We are using ASP.Net identity for user authentication. Our security team has requested when a user enters valid username but wrong password the response should be the same as invalid username and password.

I am using the following to sign in user:

```
await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(loginDetails.Username, loginDetails.Password, false, true);
```

when the browser returns response , I see the following cookies for invalid credentials.

```
HeaderSetCookie = 
{.AspNetCore.Identity.Application=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; samesite=lax,Identity.External=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; samesite=lax,Identity.TwoFactorUserId=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; samesit...
}
```

Is there some configuration which can take off these cookies?

Thank you!

Comment: How are response message and taking off cookies related?

Comment: Browser response displays these cookies in the response header. We do not want to  display these cookies for invalid user credentials which might help the hacker to understand that it is a valid user id. We would like to return the same response for both invalid user name or invalid password. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Try to use `Response.Headers.Remove("Set-Cookie");` in the Logout Post request method , but this will delete all the cookie with the key `Set-Cookie`.

Comment: Thank You  so much Xueli Chen. That worked.